# Uncaught ReferenceError: ionic is not defined

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

The ionic app showing Uncaught ReferenceError: ionic is not defined log when open in browser for testing and show blank in mobile device.Have any solution to solve this problem?.

Comment: you need to add ionic.bundle.js

Comment: but I have already add it.

Comment: could you add more code..

Comment: When you say "when open in browser for testing", how do you exactly do that? Do you use `ionic serve` command?

Comment: no by using ionic serve --lab

Comment: check if you have added ionic.bundle.js before any other js or not.
ionic.bundle.js should be on top.

Comment: Any solutions yet, the above solutions are useless.

Comment: if you install ionic-platform-web-client via bower, you need to add ionic and ionic.service.core depedencies manually at app.js

Answer (score 2):

After adding ionic-platform-web-client and push-plugin.
Adding Ionic.io(); before i declared the ionic.push() solved the problem for me.

Comment: did the problem occur for ionic push or just from the start?

Answer (score 0):

Just go with this:

```
ionic io init

ionic config set dev_push false //or true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to install the 'gulp' globally to fix it.

```
npm install gulp -g
```